# Не отображать ошибку в консоли С++

Tags: c++, консоль

подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то отключить сообщение об ошибке exp:OVERFLOW error?
просто у меня экспонента в числителе и знаменателе и даже при переполнении они сокращаются и результат удовлетворительный(проверено), а сообщение об ошибке портит мне внешний вид результата.

Comment: переписать код так, что бы этого сообщения не было. Либо показать код, может там явные проблемы есть.

Comment: проблема там одна - в степени экспоненты стоит функция, зависящая от параметра, и при определенных ее значениях возникает переполнение. Ввиду того, что компилятор даже после сообщения об ошибке проводит вычисления, исходя из того, что у него поместилось в памяти, результат получается правильный. Вопрос в том, можно ли отключить сообщения об ошибках (может какой то ключ указать при компиляции или ...)?

Comment: я подозреваю, что программа должна была бы закрыться, если произошло переполнение. Возможно Вы уже добавили try-catch. Но, скорее всего Вы используете UB (неопределенное поведение). Скорее всего на текущих данных оно магическим образом все правильно считает. Но где гарантия, что на других данных результат будет правильный. Либо расчеты, приводящие к этой ошибке не влияют на конечный результат и могут быть просто выброшены.

Comment: я тоже обычно привык, что программа закрывается при обнаружении переполнения типов, но тут видимо что то другое, так как выдает переполнение экспоненты. задача разовая для конкретного набора данных. решил проблему следующим образом: посчитал, очистил экран, вывел результат. вопрос считаю закрытым, спасибо за участие.

Comment: Так у Вас сообщение **во время выполнения?**. Просто из вопроса это не очевидно.

Можете просто для данного участка кода перекинуть stderr в /dev/null, а потом вернуть.

Comment: При наличии особой точки надо немного думать, а не пытаться заглушить проблему программистскими методами. Думать надо (чем, я полагаю, знают все)

Comment: Там не особая точка. необходимо протабулировать функцию в контрольной работе. функция вида f(t)=k(t)*(exp(a(t))-1)/(exp(a(t))+1).Зависимость a(t) зависит от варианта и в моем случае задана некорректно, так как вызывает переполнение exp при использовании типов ограниченной точности.При выводе в цикле выводится ошибка, но значение тоже выводится.Проверив значения в Maple (неограниченная точность), выяснил что результат правильный.Но красивый результат портили сообщения об ошибке.Думал, что можно как то отключить вывод ошибки в консоль, о чем и спросил.Ответ avp вроде в тему, буду пробовать.